# Google AppEngine startup takes too long for Spring Boot Application

Tags: spring-boot, google-app-engine, gcloud, google-cloud-sql

I developed a Spring Boot Application with Java 17 and Spring Boot Version 3.0.1.
Furthermore, I use Google Cloud SQL (MySQL) as my database.
My app.yml for the deployment is very simple and looks like the following:

```yaml
runtime: java17
```

When I send a GET-request the appengine starts up, but I still get a 500 response. I think that it takes too long for the app to start and thats why I get a 500 response.
One fix would be to add the following line to my app.yml:

```yaml
runtime: java17
manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
```

That would prevent my appengine from shutting down. Everything works like this, but I don't want my app to continuously run.

Is there any other possibility? Or are there any other explanations why I might get a 500 response?

**EDIT:** Here is more information and a running minimal version of my project:

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-parent
2.7.6


4.0.0
Backend
Backend
backend.project

```
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<description>Backend w/ Spring Boot</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.1</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>



<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-sql-mysql</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <!-- setting a property to "GCLOUD_CONFIG" will deploy using the gcloud settings for the property -->
                <projectId>GCLOUD_CONFIG</projectId>
                <!-- set the GAE version or use "GCLOUD_CONFIG" for an autogenerated GAE version -->
                <version>GCLOUD_CONFIG</version>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.cloud.gcp.sql.database-name=testing
spring.cloud.gcp.sql.instance-connection-name=<my-private-connection-name>

# So app starts despite "table already exists" errors.
spring.datasource.continue-on-error=true
# Enforces database initialization
spring.sql.init.mode=always

# Leave empty for root, uncomment and fill out if you specified a user
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=<my-private-root-password>

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create

spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

**UserController.java**

```java
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import java.util.List;

@RestController
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @PostMapping("/add")
    public User signUp(@RequestBody User user) {
        User usr = this.userService.addUser(user);
        return usr;
    }

    @GetMapping("/get")
    public List<User> getAll() {
        return this.userService.getAll();
    }


}
```

**UserService.java**

```java
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import java.util.List;

@Service
public class UserService {
    @Autowired private UserRepo userRepo;

    public User addUser(User user) {
        this.userRepo.save(user);
        return user;
    }

    public List<User> getAll() {
        return this.userRepo.findAll();
    }
}
```

**UserRepo.java**

```java
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface UserRepo extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {}
```

**User.java**

```java
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;


@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String username;
    private String password;
}
```

**BackendApplication.java**

```java
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("backend.project.Backend")
public class BackendApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BackendApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Here is also the console output **without** the manual scaling:

```
2022-12-30 19:15:02 default[20221230t200150]    .   ____          _            __ _ _
2022-12-30 19:15:02 default[20221230t200150]   /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
2022-12-30 19:15:02 default[20221230t200150]  ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
2022-12-30 19:15:02 default[20221230t200150]   \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
2022-12-30 19:15:02 default[20221230t200150]    '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
2022-12-30 19:15:02 default[20221230t200150]   =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
2022-12-30 19:15:02 default[20221230t200150]   :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.7.6)
2022-12-30 19:15:02 default[20221230t200150]  2022-12-30 19:15:02.323  INFO 10 --- [           main] b.p.Backend.BackendApplication     : Starting BackendApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT using Java 17.0.5 on localhost with PID 10 (/workspace/Backend-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar started by www-data in /workspace)
2022-12-30 19:15:02 default[20221230t200150]  2022-12-30 19:15:02.327  INFO 10 --- [           main] b.p.Backend.BackendApplication     : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2022-12-30 19:15:03 default[20221230t200150]  2022-12-30 19:15:03.353  INFO 10 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2022-12-30 19:15:03 default[20221230t200150]  2022-12-30 19:15:03.441  INFO 10 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 74 ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
2022-12-30 19:15:04 default[20221230t200150]  2022-12-30 19:15:04.633  INFO 10 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2022-12-30 19:15:04 default[20221230t200150]  2022-12-30 19:15:04.651  INFO 10 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2022-12-30 19:15:04 default[20221230t200150]  2022-12-30 19:15:04.651  INFO 10 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.69]
2022-12-30 19:15:04 default[20221230t200150]  2022-12-30 19:15:04.750  INFO 10 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2022-12-30 19:15:04 default[20221230t200150]  2022-12-30 19:15:04.750  INFO 10 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2320 ms
2022-12-30 19:15:05 default[20221230t200150]  Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'. The driver is automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver class is generally unnecessary.
2022-12-30 19:15:05 default[20221230t200150]  2022-12-30 19:15:05.535  INFO 10 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2022-12-30 19:15:05 default[20221230t200150]  2022-12-30 19:15:05.634  INFO 10 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.14.Final
2022-12-30 19:15:05 default[20221230t200150]  2022-12-30 19:15:05.890  INFO 10 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2022-12-30 19:15:06 default[20221230t200150]  2022-12-30 19:15:06.050  INFO 10 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2022-12-30 19:15:06 default[20221230t200150]  2022-12-30 19:15:06.055  WARN 10 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource  : Registered driver with driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver was not found, trying direct instantiation.
2022-12-30 19:15:06 default[20221230t200150]  2022-12-30 19:15:06.164  INFO 10 --- [           main] c.g.cloud.sql.core.CoreSocketFactory     : Connecting to Cloud SQL instance [<my-private-instance-connection-name>] via SSL socket.
2022-12-30 19:15:06 default[20221230t200150]  2022-12-30 19:15:06.164  INFO 10 --- [           main] c.g.cloud.sql.core.CoreSocketFactory     : First Cloud SQL connection, generating RSA key pair.
2022-12-30 19:15:07 default[20221230t200150]  2022-12-30 19:15:07.527  INFO 10 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2022-12-30 19:15:07 default[20221230t200150]  2022-12-30 19:15:07.580  INFO 10 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
2022-12-30 19:15:07 default[20221230t200150]  2022-12-30 19:15:07.633  INFO 10 --- [onnection adder] c.g.cloud.sql.core.CoreSocketFactory     : Connecting to Cloud SQL instance [<my-private-instance-connection-name>] via SSL socket.
2022-12-30 19:15:07 default[20221230t200150]  2022-12-30 19:15:07.656  INFO 10 --- [onnection adder] c.g.cloud.sql.core.CoreSocketFactory     : Connecting to Cloud SQL instance [<my-private-instance-connection-name>] via SSL socket.
2022-12-30 19:15:07 default[20221230t200150]  2022-12-30 19:15:07.681  INFO 10 --- [onnection adder] c.g.cloud.sql.core.CoreSocketFactory     : Connecting to Cloud SQL instance [<my-private-instance-connection-name>] via SSL socket.
2022-12-30 19:15:07 default[20221230t200150]  2022-12-30 19:15:07.740  INFO 10 --- [onnection adder] c.g.cloud.sql.core.CoreSocketFactory     : Connecting to Cloud SQL instance [<my-private-instance-connection-name>] via SSL socket.
2022-12-30 19:15:07 default[20221230t200150]  2022-12-30 19:15:07.768  INFO 10 --- [onnection adder] c.g.cloud.sql.core.CoreSocketFactory     : Connecting to Cloud SQL instance [<my-private-instance-connection-name>] via SSL socket.
2022-12-30 19:15:07 default[20221230t200150]  2022-12-30 19:15:07.821  INFO 10 --- [onnection adder] c.g.cloud.sql.core.CoreSocketFactory     : Connecting to Cloud SQL instance [<my-private-instance-connection-name>] via SSL socket.
2022-12-30 19:15:07 default[20221230t200150]  2022-12-30 19:15:07.856  INFO 10 --- [onnection adder] c.g.cloud.sql.core.CoreSocketFactory     : Connecting to Cloud SQL instance [<my-private-instance-connection-name>] via SSL socket.
2022-12-30 19:15:07 default[20221230t200150]  2022-12-30 19:15:07.876  INFO 10 --- [onnection adder] c.g.cloud.sql.core.CoreSocketFactory     : Connecting to Cloud SQL instance [<my-private-instance-connection-name>] via SSL socket.
2022-12-30 19:15:07 default[20221230t200150]  2022-12-30 19:15:07.936  INFO 10 --- [onnection adder] c.g.cloud.sql.core.CoreSocketFactory     : Connecting to Cloud SQL instance [<my-private-instance-connection-name>] via SSL socket.
2022-12-30 19:15:08 default[20221230t200150]  2022-12-30 19:15:08.636  INFO 10 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2022-12-30 19:15:08 default[20221230t200150]  2022-12-30 19:15:08.652  INFO 10 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2022-12-30 19:15:09 default[20221230t200150]  2022-12-30 19:15:09.140  WARN 10 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2022-12-30 19:15:09 default[20221230t200150]  2022-12-30 19:15:09.528  INFO 10 --- [           main] c.g.c.s.core.DefaultCredentialsProvider  : Default credentials provider for Google Compute Engine.
2022-12-30 19:15:09 default[20221230t200150]  2022-12-30 19:15:09.529  INFO 10 --- [           main] c.g.c.s.core.DefaultCredentialsProvider  : Scopes in use by default credentials: [https://www.googleapis.com/auth/pubsub, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spanner.admin, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spanner.data, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/datastore, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/sqlservice.admin, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudruntimeconfig, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/trace.append, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-vision, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring.write]
2022-12-30 19:15:09 default[20221230t200150]  2022-12-30 19:15:09.539  INFO 10 --- [           main] c.g.c.s.a.c.GcpContextAutoConfiguration  : The default project ID is <my-private-instance-connection-name>
2022-12-30 19:15:09 default[20221230t200150]  2022-12-30 19:15:09.696  INFO 10 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2022-12-30 19:15:09 default[20221230t200150]  2022-12-30 19:15:09.726  INFO 10 --- [           main] b.p.Backend.BackendApplication     : Started BackendApplication in 8.556 seconds (JVM running for 10.041)
2022-12-30 19:15:09 default[20221230t200150]  2022-12-30 19:15:09.771  INFO 10 --- [ionShutdownHook] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2022-12-30 19:15:09 default[20221230t200150]  2022-12-30 19:15:09.773  INFO 10 --- [ionShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2022-12-30 19:15:09 default[20221230t200150]  2022-12-30 19:15:09.826  INFO 10 --- [ionShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
```

Here also the 500-response:

```html
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<title>500 Server Error</title>
</head>
<body text=#000000 bgcolor=#ffffff>
<h1>Error: Server Error</h1>
<h2>The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.<p>Please try again in 30 seconds.</h2>
<h2></h2>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Can you provide the exact error 500? Also, would it be possible to provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: I ran into another issue that now interrupts my connection to my database. Hence, I will fix this one first and then provide a minimal reproducible example! I will keep you updated.

Comment: Alright, I edited my question. Hopefully this gives you more insights @RobertG

Comment: @Lars did you manage to fix the issue?

Comment: @FlávioFerreira unfortunately not

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar problem and I solved it by using automatic_scaling.

Accordingly to Google App engine [instances startup documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/python/how-instances-are-managed#startup) I believe that if you enable automatic scaling with min_instances as zero you would probably have a similar behaviour as basic scaling. Since automatic scaling doesn't call the `/_ah/start` it should work properly even if your app takes more than 30 seconds to start.

> Manual, basic, and automatically scaling instances startup
> differently. When you start a manual scaling instance, App Engine
> immediately sends a /_ah/start request to each instance. When you
> start an instance of a basic scaling service, App Engine allows it to
> accept traffic, but the /_ah/start request is not sent to an instance
> until it receives its first user request. Multiple basic scaling
> instances are only started as necessary, in order to handle increased
> traffic. Automatically scaling instances do not receive any /_ah/start
> request.

Something like:

```
automatic_scaling:
  target_cpu_utilization: 0.80
  min_instances: 0
  max_instances: 1
```

Be aware that there are some differences between automatic_scaling and the other scaling strategies so it may not apply to your use case (check differences [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/python/how-instances-are-managed#scaling_types))